# cannot access my webserver from outside the network

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have set up a web server on port 3000 and set up port forwarding on the router to correctly forward all requests from port 80 to 3000 on my machine by stating the local ip of my machine. I have also disabled the firewall. Still when I try to hit the server using public IP of the network, the browser shows the address is unreachable. I am giving below the output of route -n command.

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp13s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp13s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp13s0
```

I really can't figure out what error is causing this to happen. If you people need some more info, I would edit the question accordingly.

EDIT

I checked if my port 80 is open on canyouseeme.org. It shows it cannot see the service due to no route to host. Also, when I ping using public ip, it shows time to live exceeded. Does it mean that the IP is blocking port 80?

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you share the IP you're able to see the in router status page? Feel free to remove the last octet and replace it with a X.

Comment: I don't remember it, but it started with 10. Something

Comment: Someone told me that I have to request my ISP for a seperate public IP address.

Comment: If it started with 10. this will be a private address. These addresses are defined in RFC1918 and are not publically routable on the internet. As mentioned on the Net Eng stack, I suspect you're sitting behind CG-NAT. If this is the case, you will need to call your provider.

Comment: Do every ISP nowadays use CGNAT??

Comment: Not every ISP no, however it is becoming more and more common in the residential space. Usually you can opt out on request.

Comment: First you'll need to confirm with them that you are behind CGNAT, if this is the case, request a static IP and or request port 80 on your current IP (If possible)

Comment: You may potentially be able to use a service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel through CGNAT (assuming that getting e.g. a static IP from your ISP isn't an option for some reason). These types of services are typically less robust depending on your needs, but just for simple access to a web server, they might fit the bill.

Comment: That's the only thing I don't wanna do. It's not any of my project, I just wanna learn how such things work.

Comment: I have now learned how to do it. There's a pocket router here in India, which we call Jio fi, provides the user with a seperate public ipv6 address. We can use it to set up our own server by forwarding the port we want.